# Does VMX Root and VMX Non-root Ring 0 enjoy same hardware privilege?

Tags: security, x86

I have found following figure from a paper (Intel SGX Explained).

[image: The privilege levels in the x86 architecture]

According to this, VMX Root Ring 0 hypervisor enjoy more privilege than VMX Non-root Ring 0 OS Kernel. My question is: other than VMX-root and Non-root difference, as they both execute in Intel Architecture Ring 0 (same privilege level), do they also enjoy the same privilege from hardware points of view?